# R error message when calling agricolae package that usually work very well

Tags: r

When I called the agricolae package by :
library(agricolae)

I got this error message :
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘agricolae’:
l'objet ‘faststack’ n'est pas exporté par 'namespace:fastmap'
In addition: Warning message:
le package ‘agricolae’ a été compilé avec la version R 4.0.5

> 

I

Then I tryed to remove and install again the agricolae package using:
remove.packages("agricolae")
install.packages("agricolae")

And I tryed to call the package again, but I got the same error message
How to fix the problem , please?

Comment: What version of R are you using? What version of `agricolae` is installed? What version of `fastmap` is installed?

Comment: I am using R 4.0.2. How to check the agricolae and the  fastmap version ? I remember that I updated my R version weeks ago

Comment: Running `installed.packages()[,"Version"]` should show the version number for all installed packages. You updated just a few weeks ago to 4.0.2? That's odd because that's at least a year and a half old. There have been 7 R releases since then.

Comment: ok. I checked the versions : agricolae "1.3-5" and fastmap "1.0.1"

Comment: Your version of `fastmap` is out of date. Run `install.packages("fastmap")` to update to version 1.1.0.